# Receiving e-mail message

Tags: java, android

How can I get the content of the last e-mail message in Android (theme and message body) if I know how to access contacts and get necessary e-mail address?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you restate it?

Answer (score 1):

This would depend on the email client being used, and in many cases won't be possible.
Google's gmail app for example no longer supports this (it never did officially, the unofficial capability is no longer available to 3rd-party apps).

You may be able to separately connect to a mail server using something like pop or imap with login credentials provided by the user to the app to get a message, if the sever permits this.

Can you accomplish what you need with an attachment, or a URL in the message, which your app would be configured to handle on the phone?